# jQuery insertBefore() after insertAfter()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you see in this https://jsfiddle.net/yxvwfh6x/ i am trying to add an element after and before of `div`.

```
var hi = $('<h1>Hi</h1>');
var div = $('div');
hi.insertAfter(div);
hi.insertBefore(div);
```

In the result `insertBefore` removes last `Hi`. Please try this code to understand what is happening.

```
var hi = $('<h1>Hi</h1>');
var div = $('div');
hi.insertAfter(div);
setTimeout(function(){
    hi.insertBefore(div);
},1000);
```

Is this bug of jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `hi` refers to the same object, so following sequence is followed

- added after first -> hi1
- added a cloned copy after second -> hi2
- Remove after first and added before first. -> hi2
- added a cloned copy before second -> hi3

use this instead

```
var div = $('div');
$('<h1>Hi</h1>').insertAfter(div);
$('<h1>Hi</h1>').insertBefore(div);
```

Comment: what about this https://jsfiddle.net/yxvwfh6x/2/
as your answer it should be remove all Hi and then add just before first element

Comment: @MohammadRezaei It took the last cloned node that was added after div2 and placed it before div1. Check my explanation again.

Comment: @MohammadRezaei updated the explanation to explain the concept of cloned and uncloned node.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not the bug of jQuery. This is because the first reference to the `'<h1>Hi</h1>'` is now in the DOM after you executed: `insertAfter()` statement. So you can change it like this:

```
var h1Text = '<h1>Hi</h1>';
var div = $('div');
$(h1Text).insertAfter(div);
$(h1Text).insertBefore(div);
```

Or you can also use the `clone()` with your existing code:

```
var hi = $('<h1>Hi</h1>');
var div = $('div');
hi.insertAfter(div);
hi.clone().insertBefore(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 var div = $('div');
 div.insertAfter(div);
 div.insertBefore(div);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="inner">1</div>
<div class="inner">2</div>


$( "<h1>Hi</h1>" ).insertBefore( ".inner" );
$( "<h1>Hi</h1>" ).insertAfter( ".inner" );
```

Try this hope it helps
JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/336z5pnt/2/